# Issue exporting a textured suit from Marvelous Desinger to Blender

Tags: rendering, texturing

So I'm creating an animated video and designed a custom textured suit in Marvelous Designer that would then be put onto a meta human in UE. After exporting the file as an FBX and importing into blender however i get all sorts of weird issues. The shoulder pads clip through the top of the suit in blender as well as a bunch of clipping issues on the rear side of the model. Any suggestions on how to to fix?[image][image][image]

Comment: Have you tried recalculating the normals?